# Apache ColdFusion cannot log into admin

Tags: apache, coldfusion

I have a server running on the Amazon cloud running ColdFusion 9.0.1. on Windows 2008 R2 and Apache 2.2
I have verified that ColdFusion is running the webroot is c:\www
I cannot access the CIIDE/Administrator page. It returns a directory listing and does not show the admin when I do something like this.
The path to CFIDE is C:\www\dev\cr\CFIDE\administrator
http://dev.mydomain.com/cfide/administrator
Here are my virtual host settings.
    
    ServerAlias dev.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/www/dev/cr"

Comment: this is probably a better question for serverfault ~  http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

You say you get only a directory listing. Is there an index.cfm in there? You don't mention using that on the URL. It may simply be that you need to add that to the URL, at least until you define index.cfm to be a default document. In apache, you could do that like:

DirectoryIndex index.cfm index.htm

If it's that there is no index.cfm in the directory listing, then what else do you see in there? That may give a clue to resolution.

Comment: There is an index.cfm and I have tried running a test.cfm that has now() dumped on the page and that works

Comment: I tried dumping test.cfm into this directory C:\www\dev\cr\CFIDE\administrator and no page is served back. No processing at all.

Comment: Those two comments almost cancel each other out. Are you saying in the first that you put the test.cfm somewhere else? And in the second, are you saying that the test.cfm then shows up in the directory listing, but then if you run it, it fails to execute?

Comment: I am saying that coldfusion is running in this directory C:\www\dev\cr when I try and run anything inside the CFIDE/administrator it does not work, this is the path for that. C:\www\dev\cr\CFIDE\administrator

Comment: Also, by "no page is served back, no processing at all", you may be assuming it's not executing in CF, but that may not be so. Check out the application.log file (in the CF logs directory) to see if perhaps an error is happening that you're not being shown. Also, might there be an application.cfm or .cfc in that directory or a parent that is being executed first, where again there may be some error to explain things?

Comment: You say, "I am saying that coldfusion is running in this directory". That's not responsive to the comment I made that you are replying to. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Hi Charlie, this is the error "Error","jrpp-3","04/03/12","11:27:34",,"Object Instantiation Exception.Class not found: coldfusion.security.ESAPIUtils The specific sequence of files included or processed is: C:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\WEB-INF\exception\coldfusion\runtime\ObjectException.cfm, line: 12 "

Comment: Please move that very important new piece of information as an answer, as it's being lost here in the comments. I'll add a reply to that with more info then.

Comment: fixed it by looking at this post. http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2011/10/21/why_chfs_may_break

Comment: Great to hear. Thanks for the clarifications and update, and "answer". Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed ColdFusion did you install the ColdFusion module for Apache. You will know if you did because it will be in your Apache Conf. Look for something along the lines of:

```
LoadModule jrun_module "c:/ColdFusion9/runtime/lib/wsconfig/1/mod_jrun.so" 
<IfModule mod_jrun.c> 
     JRunConfig Verbose false 
     JRunConfig Apialloc false 
     JRunConfig Ssl false 
     JRunConfig IgnoreSuffixmap false 
     JRunConfig Serverstore "c:/ColdFusion9/runtime/lib/wsconfig/1/jrunserver.store" 
     JRunConfig Bootstrap 127.0.0.1:51000 
     #JRunConfig Errorurl <optionally redirect to this URL on errors> 
     JRunConfig jrun-handler .jsp .jws .cfm .cfml .cfc .cfswf .cfr 
</IfModule>
```

If its not there, then follow the instructions below:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Installing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cdec18a15-7ffb.html

Comment: Yes I verified that the jrun_module is installed

Answer (score 0):

Just a small point here.

The CF admin may not always be at c:\the_path_you_think\cfide\administrator

Put #cgi.server_name# in a cfm file and run it on your server.

Whatever path you get from here, do the following for admin  new_path\cfide\administrator.

Answer (score 0):

If Apache config and the CF server is running with error, but you still cannot access the admin due to what seems like a timeout then make sure you have approved port 8500 in the security group. EC2 using the CF 2016 AMI installs a Coldfusion Security Group, but port 8500 isn't included in that security group.